# Suppress void context warning for overloaded operator

Tags: perl, operator-overloading, warnings

Is there a means to suppress specific warnings in the caller for an overloaded operator?

**Background:**  I'm looking at a module that overloads `<=` and `>=` to implement a sort of declarative domain specific alnguage.  Whether or not that's a good idea aside, these operators throw "Useless use in void context" warnings when used in a void context.  Something like:

```
package Boundary;

use strict;
use overload ('<=' => \&set_min, '>=' => \&set_max);

sub new     { my ($class, $min, $max) = @_; bless [ $min, $max ], $class; }
sub set_min { my $self = shift; $self->[0] = shift; }
sub set_max { my $self = shift; $self->[1] = shift; }

package main;

# user code
use warnings;

my $bound = Boundary->new();
$bound >=  1;  # Useless use of numeric ge (>=) in void context at ...
$bound <= 10;  # Useless use of numeric le (>=) in void context at ...
```

Is there a way to suppress the warnings just for the overloaded calls, without the caller having to explicitly disable 'void' warnings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl expects that you preserve existing semantics when you overload an operator. e.g. It sometimes optimises negation away. You're playing with fire.

```
$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'$y = !$x;'
1  <0> enter
2  <;> nextstate(main 1 -e:1) v:{
3  <$> gvsv(*x) s
4  <1> not sK/1                    <--- "not" operator
5  <$> gvsv(*y) s
6  <2> sassign vKS/2
7  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC
-e syntax OK

$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'if (!$x) { f() }'
1  <0> enter 
2  <;> nextstate(main 3 -e:1) v:{
3  <$> gvsv(*x) s
4  <|> or(other->5) vK/1           <--- No "not" operator
5      <0> pushmark s
6      <$> gv(*f) s/EARLYCV
7      <1> entersub[t1] vKS/TARG,1
8  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC
-e syntax OK
```

Comment: +1  Thanks, good illustration.  I don't think it's that dangero — AAAUUGH IT BURNS!!!

Comment: @pilcrow, No, you're right about it not likely to be changed any time soon. The point you will run into these kinds of problems because your model and that of the porters is not in sync.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you overload the `<<=` and `>>=` operators instead as the compiler expects them to be used for their side-effects. Alternatively you may prefer `-=` and `+=`.

You would need to return `$self` from the overload subroutines, as the LHS of an operator like this is set to the return value and you don't want it to change.

Comment: +1. You could even chain them: `( $bound >>= 1 ) <<= 10;` (I don't like the idea of using operators to do this, but this would be a good way to do it if one were to use operators.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no possibility, I **guess**. The only solutions I have is:

- change your API
- live with this warnings (you can filter them via `__WARN__` pseudo signal handler)
- use weird syntax:

  $bound >= 1 or 0;

I think the first choice is best ;)

Comment: Hmm, I was thinking there might be a dirty trick that could be played with `${^WARNING_BITS}`